# How have dialectology surveys changed over the years?

Tags: sociolinguistics, dialects, dialect-mapping

*Apologies for any ill terminology I may use, I'm pretty new to the field

I've been working on the transition of dialectology surveys from the traditional methods to the modern ones, now that we not only have better technology to collect and analyze data but also have realized some ways in which we might have overlooked certain features either consciously or simply due to the way the questionnaires are framed.

I've been following "Introducing Sociolinguistics - Rajend Mesthrie" up till now.
I'd love to get more insight into this. I've done some digging on the net to get old survey questionnaires, but so far no luck. So it'd be a huge help if I could get hands on a few.

Thanks in advance :)

link to the above mentioned book- http://home.lu.lv/~pva/Sociolingvistika/0710892_68436_mesthrie_rajend_et_al_introducing_sociolinguistics.pdf

Comment: Bu the use of statistics and computer sciences (GIS, machine learning). Otherwise concepts are almost unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for responding promptly :), I actually meant the way in which survey questionnaires are framed, as in initially surveys included primarily old people from rural background (called N.O.R.Ms : Non-mobile.Old.Rural.Male) ;D, so wanted more info about the sociolinguistic aspect of it.

Comment: In this case, nothing has really changed too. It is just the use of new technologies such as the survey of Labov using the phone to contact informants (The Atlas of North American English).

Comment: Oh ok. Still, thanks a lot. I'm new to a forum like this, and you were really helpful and prompt :)

Comment: There is also the use of websites to gather data, here is a French example: https://neuchatel.eu.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_abItPLPL2EE64qF ... If this methodology is used, it means that the sampling is not controled, so biases can be present in your corpus.